# How to create a VPN between a Host and VMWare VMs?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vmware, vpn, windows-server-2003

I  have a set of machines as follows

My home laptop running Win7 Ultimate with internet connection.
A vmware workstation vm running Windows Server 2003 Standard edition server in my laptop w/o internet connectivity
Some of my peers' machines connected to internet
I want to create a VPN with these machines, provided the VM will not have any direct internet connection and my peers should able to connect to the SVN server running on this Win2003 server VM.

Can anybody please suggest me how to setup this network, what software I need to install in both physical machine and vm, what kind of network connectivity should be there between vmware guest and host machine?

Answer (score 0):

If the network connection between the host and the VM is bridged, then you just have to install RRAS for windows 2003 and forward the ports on the router to that IP.